# #1329 -No data-zero rows fetched,selected, or processed

Tags: mysql, stored-procedure

Buen día tengo en mi base de datos(MySQL) la siguiente tabla:
[image: Tabla, "transaccion_cta_cli"]

Para obtener el saldo de una cuenta en cierto día, uso la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT  (@total := @total+IFNULL(SUM(tcc.consumo),0.00)-IFNULL(SUM(tcc.pago),0.00)) saldo FROM transaccion_cta_cli tcc JOIN (SELECT @total := 0) acumulados WHERE tcc.no_cta=1000 AND tcc.fecha<='2018-08-25' ORDER BY tcc.fecha
```

Posteriormente realicé una función(SF) que al pasarle como parametros: la fecha y no_cta, me arroja el mismo saldo que la consulta anterior, es decir, la consulta la incorporé dentro de la función.

```
    DELIMITER /
CREATE FUNCTION saldos_2(fecha DATE,cuenta INT ) 
RETURNS DECIMAL(13,2)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
DECLARE saldo DECIMAL(13,2);
SET saldo = ( SELECT  (@total := @total+IFNULL(SUM(tcc.consumo),0.00)-IFNULL(SUM(tcc.pago),0.00)) saldo FROM transaccion_cta_cli tcc JOIN (SELECT @total := 0) acumulados WHERE tcc.no_cta=cuenta AND tcc.fecha<=fecha ORDER BY tcc.fecha );
RETURN saldo;
END 
/
DELIMITER ;
```

La idea es saber el saldo, en cierta fecha y de todas mis cuentas que tengo registradas en la siguiente tabla:
[image: Tabla donde tengo las cuentas y se clasifican por tipo(crédito,débito)]

Para saber dicho saldo de todas mis cuentas registradas en la tabla anterior, mi idea fue crear un procedimiento(SP) que recorre las cuentas(no_cta) registras en la tabla **ctabanc** y las va guardando en una variable del SP llamada: **cuenta**, que recupero con el `FETCH cursor_ctabanc INTO cuenta;` y el valor de la **cuenta(no_cta)** y la **fecha** pasada como parámetro al procedimiento, posteriormente  pasarlas como parámetro a la función mencionada anteriormente `SET sa = (SELECT saldos_2(fecha,cuenta));` y guardar el saldo de las cuentas y su no_cta en una tabla temporal,`CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE saldos_clientes(no_cta INT,saldo DECIMAL(13,2));`  y al final, retornar la suma de los saldos. Dicho procedimiento, es el siguiente:

```
DELIMITER /

CREATE PROCEDURE saldos(IN fecha DATE, OUT saldos_client DECIMAL(13,2) ) 
BEGIN
DECLARE cuenta INT;
DECLARE sa DECIMAL(13,2);
DECLARE fin INT DEFAULT 0;

DECLARE cursor_ctabanc CURSOR FOR
SELECT no_cta FROM ctabanc;

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '20000' SET fin = 1;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE saldos_clientes(no_cta INT,saldo DECIMAL(13,2));
OPEN cursor_ctabanc;
    REPEAT
        FETCH cursor_ctabanc INTO cuenta;
            SET sa = (SELECT saldos_2(fecha,cuenta));

            INSERT INTO saldos_clientes(no_cta,saldo) VALUES(cuenta,sa);
    UNTIL fin=1
    END REPEAT;
CLOSE cursor_ctabanc;
     SELECT SUM(saldo) sal INTO saldos_client FROM saldos_clientes;
END 
/
DELIMITER ;
```

Solo que al mandar llamar el procedimiento anterior, me arroja el siguiente error:

[image: Llamar el procedimiento saldos]

Ojala alguien me pueda ayudar, se los agradecería, ya que en un reporte que me piden, necesito calcular la sumatoria de todos los saldos, de todas las cuentas en cierta fecha y mi idea era ejecutar el procedimiento con otra función, que al pasarle una fecha me retornara el saldo que se supone me arrojaría el procedimiento.

Comment: PArece un bug de mysql.. mira [aca](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3463283/73749). Tal vez si alguna de esas soluciones te funciona podes traducirla?

Comment: Muchas gracias @gbianchi  lo revisare en seguida!

Comment: Busque en la liga que me proporcionaste, realicé algunos cambios y me siguió tirando el error, cambie el `REPEAT` por un `LOOP` y ya no me tira el error, pero sigue sin mostrar datos de retorno.